# MySQL query - force case-sensitive with a ORDER BY rand( )

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

Is it possible to force case-sensitive for a query?

Mine sounds like this:

```
"SELECT g_path FROM glyphs WHERE g_glyph = :g_glyph ORDER BY rand()"
```

if g_glyph = r, the result can be R or r and it's not what I expect.
I'm looking for a case-sensitive return.

I googled my issue and I found this solution:

```
/*Case-sensitive sort in descending order.
In this query, ProductName is sorted in 
case-sensitive descending order.
*/
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitsInStock
FROM products
ORDER BY BINARY ProductName DESC;
```

But the following line doesn't work at all:

```
"SELECT g_path FROM glyphs WHERE g_glyph = :g_glyph ORDER BY BINARY rand()"
```

Any Suggestion?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: do you have g_glyph  declared as binary ?

Comment: What collation does your column have?

Comment: Thank you for the interest in my issue.
The Gumbo's solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order and equality of characters is defined by the [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-general.html). In most cases, a case-insensitive collation is used.

If you need to use a strict, case-sensitive comparison for a specific datum, use the [`BINARY` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-binary-op.html):

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'A';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT BINARY 'a' = 'A';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT BINARY 'a' = 'a ';
        -> 0
```

So in your case:

```
SELECT g_path FROM glyphs WHERE BINARY g_glyph = :g_glyph ORDER BY rand()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gumbo !
It's exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the manual page [Case Sensitivity in String Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html).

You need to specify a case sensitive or binary collation.

> The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a. To make this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a case sensitive or binary collation. For example, if you are comparing a column and a string that both have the latin1 character set, you can use the COLLATE operator to cause either operand to have the latin1_general_cs or latin1_bin collation:
>
> ```
> col_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE 'a%'
> col_name LIKE 'a%' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
> col_name COLLATE latin1_bin LIKE 'a%'
> col_name LIKE 'a%' COLLATE latin1_bin
> ```
>
> If you want a column always to be treated in case-sensitive fashion, declare it with a case sensitive or binary collation. See Section 13.1.14, “CREATE TABLE Syntax”.

The `_cs` in the collation name stands for "case sensitive".

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My DB specs:
- type: InnoDB
- interclassement: utf8_general_ci

If I just change the interclassement utf8_general_ci to utf8_bin, may I obtain the expected result (case-sensitive result) or must I convert all my DB's data?

Comment: The "_ci" means case insensitive. You should use case sensitive (_cs) instead. Bin means A binary comparison, which is more strict than case sensitive.