# Arrange song list in alphabetical order case insensitive

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am following code to display song list in alphabetical order

```
function getSongsIn(key, value)
{
    var query= "SELECT * FROM Songs where " + key + "=\"" + value + "\"ORDER BY title ;" ; 
    SongsDB.transaction(function (tx) {
        //tx.executeSql(query,[],showSongsIn,onError);
        tx.executeSql(query,[],showSongs,onError);
        }); 
}
```

Above code result in case sensitive arrangement.
Can anyone suggest me to make it case insensitive?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/973777/464744

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413427/how-to-use-sql-order-by-statement-to-sort-results-case-insensitive

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160556/mysql-query-force-case-sensitive-with-a-order-by-rand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
ORDER BY upper(title)
```